# Elements of order $p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a $p$-group with $n$ elements of order $p$ then $n \equiv -1 \operatorname{mod} p$.

Someone can help me for this statement? Thanks for you time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fill the following in:

Let $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ act on

$$X=\left\{(g_1,\ldots,g_p)\in G^p:g_1\cdots g_p=1\right\}$$

by having $k$ cyclically shift the tuple forward $k$ terms. Note then that the fix set $X^G$ is precisely the elements of $G$ of order $p$, and $1$. But, by basic group theory

$$\#(X^G)\equiv |G|\mod p$$

and so $p\mid \#(X^G)$ but, $\#(X^G)=n+1$.

Comment: i do not understand the "Fill the following in" hehe

Comment: I mean, you should fill in the missing steps to my proof (this is actually a famous proof by some guy).

Comment: oo ok ok, a question in the context of you answer what is the meaning of your action,i.e, can you explain me you action "by having k cyclically shift the tuple forward k terms".Please.

Comment: @Knight So, $k\cdot (a_1,\ldots,a_p)=(a_{p-k+1},\ldots,a_{p-k})$. So, if $p=5$ and $k=2$ then $2\cdot (a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5)$ is $(a_4,a_5,a_1,a_2,a_3)$.

Comment: @Alex - actually not "a famous proof by some guy", but "a proof by some famous guy": James McKay. Another proof of Cauchy's group theorem, American Math. Monthly, 66 (1959), p. 119.

Comment: @NickyHekster Is this him? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_McKay_(fur_trader) :)

Comment: @Alex LOL! James should not be confused with John McKay, the guy of Monstrous Moonshine and simple groups.